# Xcode: Get dictionary key from URL not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary

I'm using the newest version of `Xcode` and `Swift`.

I have the following code to get the current URL of a `WKWebView`:

```
let htmlURL = navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteURL
print(htmlURL)
```

The `print` function outputs exactly the following: `https://www.example.com/`

Now, I have the following code:

```
if let htmlSourceCode = dict[htmlURL] {
    print(htmlSourceCode)
} else {
    print("key not found")
}
```

For some reason, this gives me: `key not found`

But when using directly `https://www.example.com/` instead of `htmlURL` like this:

```
if let htmlSourceCode = dict["https://www.example.com/"] {
    print(htmlSourceCode)
} else {
    print("key not found")
}
```

it's working and showing me the source code in console as expected.

Why is it working with `dict["https://www.example.com/"]` but not with `dict[htmlURL]` although is's the exactly same string in both cases?

**EDIT:**

`dict` is the following:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "html", ofType: "plist") {
let dictRoot = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
if let dict = dictRoot {
}
```

Comment: What is `dict`? Please add it.

Comment: It means you are validate the your dict as key , you validate with value of dict , add your dict in here

Comment: What are you getting in `dict`? Print it and paste it in here, so we can see what values are present in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `URL`'s `absoluteString` as the `dict`'s key. Try this:

```
if let htmlSourceCode = dict[htmlURL.absoluteString] {
    print(htmlSourceCode)
} else {
    print("key not found")
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You should have added the `dict` declaration in question. I've made a 
similar mistake so I could recognise your issue.